TFVC Azure DevOps server 2022 - How to check a file is checkout or not using C#
How to check a file is checkout or not using TfvcItem? Trying to use TfvcItem.IsPendingChange, but not helpful.
I am using DevOps Server 2022 and TFVC as a repo.
lang-cs
TfvcItem file = sourceControl.GetItemAsync(sSrcPath).Result; //retun the file
bool ret = file.IsPendingChange; //always false. I wanted to check the file in TFVS is checked out or not.

Previous version of the code is like this
String serverPath = sRegion + sPath_Tfs + sName_File;
String[] str = new String[1];
str[0] = serverPath;
PendingSet[] pendingSet = sourceControl.GetPendingSets(str,RecursionType.Full);


Well, as a starting point, a "pending change" is not synonymous with "checked out". A file that contains a pending change is checked out, but a checked out file is not a pending change.

It's also worth keeping in mind that most TFVC users have, for over a decade, used local workspaces which does not automatically reflect a file that a user has begun editing as "checked out" -- a checkout becomes a rare, explicit action.

I have tried to use TfvcItem.IsPendingChange to check whether files are checked out or not. But it keeps as false even though I indeed checked them out. It's suggested that you can use tf status command to get information about pending changes to files and folders. See the detailed info from Status command.

I have tried to use TfvcItem.IsPendingChange to check whether files are checked out or not. But it keeps as false even though I indeed checked them out.
It's suggested that you can use tf status command to get information about pending changes to files and folders. See the detailed info from Status command.
